# polynomial fitting on spectral data

Tags: r, curve-fitting, raster, polynomials

I want to fit a polynomial function (max. 3rd order) on each raster cell over all my spectral bands (Landsat 1-7) creating a new raster(stack) representing the coefficients.
I got my data (including NA values) in a stack with 6 Layer (Landsat Band 1-7[excluding 6]).

I guess somehow I should tell the polynomial function on which spectral wavelength the bands are located

1. Landsat7    Wavelength (micrometers)

   - Band 1   0.45-0.52
   - Band 2   0.52-0.60
   - Band 3   0.63-0.69
   - Band 4   0.77-0.90
   - Band 5   1.55-1.75
   - Band 7   2.09-2.35

so that it can fit it properly.
Has anyone an idea how to do that polynomial fitting of each cell and extracting the coefficients in R? Thanks for any help!

Comment: edit: my NA-values are on the same position in each band (rasterlayer) - so exact the same amount on the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, as you do not specify what you are fitting. I am guessing it is band number. You can do something like this.

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
b[[2]][125:225] <- NA
s <- stack(b, flip(b, 'y'))
names(s) <- paste0('b', 1:6)
bands <- 1:6
f <- function(x) {
    # in case of NAs; match the number of coefficients returned
    if (any(is.na(x))) return(c(NA, NA, NA))
    m <- lm(x ~ bands + I(bands^2))
    coefficients(m)
}
z <- calc(s, f)
z
plot(z)
```

If you need to speed this up you can follow the example here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144211/want-cell-linear-regression-values-for-a-netcdf-or-multi-band-raster/144408#144408

Comment: Indeed i want to fit band number - to **get the spectral curve or signature for each pixel value**. Thanks very much for the snippet - but **isn't it necessary to specify the wavelength for the bands as they differ in their "distance" to one another?** (wavelength of Band 1 leads directly into Band 2 - whereas between Band 4 and Band 5 are about 0.6 micrometers difference in wavelength (that is not covered by measurement)). I guess this should be taken into account in my fitting? (The 6 Bands on my X-Axis [Y representing intensity of reflectance] are not of equal distance to one another...)

Comment: You can certainly replace bands by a vector of wavelenghts. Whether that is sensible or not I cannot know, as I do not have any context or why you want to do this.

Comment: I tried to apply the function on a rasterstack with NA values and unfortunately it did not work. (I also tried: `d <- na.omit(data.frame(x))#
  if (nrow(d) < 3) return(NA)#
m <- lm(x ~ bands + I(bands^2)#`). Should it work with NAs?

Concerning the context: I want to add additional info to my data. So for each pixel not only the observed values in the 6 spectral bands but also an approximation of a curve representing the spectral signature of the pixel will be basis for further mapping. Unfortunately so far I wasn't able to fit a polynomial function matching good the observed value.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to deal with NAs